# how to remove super admin from dropdown if user is login

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

[image: I have to remove the super user from form showing in frontend. Means when I am creating todo and I also choosing user, so super admin is also display in dropdwn so I didn't try anything because i dont know how to do it and i am using built user model]

Please help me.

I have to remove the super user from form showing in frontend. Means when I am creating todo and I also choosing user, so super admin is also display in dropdwn so I didn't try anything because i dont know how to do it and i am using built user model

Comment: You forgot to add your relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

In your views instead of `Users.objects.all()` try adding a filter:

```
Users.objects..filter(is_superuser=False)
```

This question is similar to [Django: Filter users by user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575397/django-filter-users-by-user-role).

Answer (score 0):

if user is super user selected then **return**

`return queryset.filter(is_superuser=False)`